# Mapping issue for decimal property

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, decimal, automapper

I have a class `ABC` that has a property `amount` which is of type `decimal`, and I have `ABCdto` that also has a decimal property `amount`.

Now I am doing a mapping from `ABC` to `ABDdto`, but I encounter this issue:

> Mapping types:
>
> SubscriptionConfigurationTransaction -> Decimal
>   CommPlat.Core.Domain.Aggregates.SubscriptionConfigurationTransactionAgg.SubscriptionConfigurationTransaction
>   -> System.Decimal
>
> Destination path:
>   SubscriptionConfigurationTransactionDto.SubscriberBalanceAfterTransaction.SubscriberBalanceAfterTransaction
>
> Source value:
>   CommPlat.Core.Domain.Aggregates.SubscriptionConfigurationTransactionAgg.SubscriptionConfigurationTransaction

Note that `SubscriberBalanceAfterTransaction` is decimal, and I am not sure why it is showing `SubscriberBalanceAfterTransaction.SubscriberBalanceAfterTransaction`!

Relevant code:

```
public class SubscriptionConfigurationTransaction
{
   public decimal balance {get {return subscriber.balance;}}
   public decimal amount {get { subscription.amount}}
   public decimal SubscriberBalanceAfterTransaction {get {return balance - amount;}}
}

public class SubscriptionConfigurationTransactionDto
{
   public decimal SubscriberBalanceAfterTransaction {get; set;}
}
```

and in global I am adding this

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SubscriberBalanceAfterTransaction, SubscriptionConfigurationTransactionDto>()
```

Comment: Please show your actual code, and learn to format please.

Comment: Also,, are you using AutoMapper here? You need to be far more careful about your question content. Right now this is unanswerable.

Comment: @DavidG updated the question, and yes i am using automapper

Comment: @DavidG i have added the code that is imporant only, as the code is huge

Comment: Maybe this instead:

Mapper.CreateMap<SubscriptionConfigurationTransaction, SubscriptionConfigurationTransactionDto>()   You've put the property instead of the class.

Comment: @EricYeoman if i am adding the properties, it is working fine, but the thing is why it is showing an issue from first place, if the names are matching no need to mach the properties

Comment: i am not sure why it is trying to map classname "SubscriptionConfigurationTransaction" to decimal !!!!

Comment: Try disabling constructor mapping.